Azure pipeline if condition not evaluating as expected
I would like to determine docker tag depending on building source branch.
What I've done so far:
variables:
  - name: isMain
    value: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/${{ parameters.releaseBranchName }}')]
    readonly: true
  - name: isStaging
    value: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/${{ parameters.stagingBranchName }}')]
    readonly: true
  - name: isDevelop
    value: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/${{ parameters.buildBranchName }}')]
    readonly: true
  - name: shouldPublish
    value: $[or(variables['isMain'], variables['isStaging'], variables['isDevelop'])]
    readonly: true

  - name: tag
    ${{ if variables['isMain'] }}:
      value: $[format('release.{0}', variables['Build.BuildNumber'])]
    ${{ elseif variables['isStaging'] }}:
      value: $[format('staging.{0}', variables['Build.BuildNumber'])]
    ${{ else }}:
      value: $[format('build.{0}', variables['Build.BuildNumber'])]
    readonly: true

which evaluates like this :
  isMain:
    Parsing expression: <eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')>
    Evaluating: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')
    Expanded: eq('refs/heads/cd', 'refs/heads/main')
    Result: 'False'
  isStaging:
    Parsing expression: <eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/cd')>
    Evaluating: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/cd')
    Expanded: eq('refs/heads/cd', 'refs/heads/cd')
    Result: 'True'
  isDevelop:
    Parsing expression: <eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop')>
    Evaluating: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop')
    Expanded: eq('refs/heads/cd', 'refs/heads/develop')
    Result: 'False'
  shouldPublish:
    Parsing expression: <or(variables['isMain'], variables['isStaging'], variables['isDevelop'])>
    Evaluating: or(variables['isMain'], variables['isStaging'], variables['isDevelop'])
    Expanded: or('False', variables['isStaging'], variables['isDevelop'])
    Result: 'True'
  tag:
    Parsing expression: <format('release.{0}', variables['Build.BuildNumber'])>
    Evaluating: format('release.{0}', variables['Build.BuildNumber'])
    Result: 'release.20240531.11'

I do not understand why the tag variable enters the first condition as "isMain" is set to false.
Could you please help?
===
Edit : also tried :
  - name: tag
    ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/${{ parameters.releaseBranchName }}') }}:
      value: $[format('release.{0}', variables['Build.BuildNumber'])]
    ${{ elseif eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/${{ parameters.stagingBranchName }}') }}:
      value: $[format('staging.{0}', variables['Build.BuildNumber'])]
    ${{ else }}:
      value: $[format('build.{0}', variables['Build.BuildNumber'])]
    readonly: true

But with above code I end in "build." (else part) which is not what I want neither.

You're mixing runtime expressions $[] with compile-time expressions ${{}}. Compile-time expressions are evaluated before runtime expressions, so your variables such as isMain aren't set yet.

How to fix then?

In order to set a variable tag depending on building source branch you can do the following:
name: $(Date:yyyyMMdd).$(Rev:r)

parameters:
  - name: releaseBranchName
    type: string
    default: 'main'

  - name: stagingBranchName
    type: string
    default: 'staging'

  - name: buildBranchName
    type: string
    default: 'develop'

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  - name: isMain
    value: ${{ contains(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], parameters.releaseBranchName) }}
    readonly: true

  - name: isStaging
    value: ${{ contains(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], parameters.stagingBranchName) }}
    readonly: true

  - name: isDevelop
    value: ${{ contains(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], parameters.buildBranchName) }}
    readonly: true

  - name: shouldPublish
    value: ${{ in(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], parameters.releaseBranchName, parameters.stagingBranchName, parameters.buildBranchName) }}
    readonly: true

  - name: tag
    # variables have always string values
    # Use $(Build.BuildId) as an alternative to $(Build.BuildNumber) 
    ${{ if eq(variables['isMain'], 'True') }}:
      value: 'release.$(Build.BuildNumber)' 
    ${{ if eq(variables['isStaging'], 'True') }}:
      value: 'staging.$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    ${{ if eq(variables['isDevelop'], 'True') }}:
      value: 'build.$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    readonly: true

stages:
- stage: Test
  displayName:  Test
  jobs:
    - job: printVariables
      displayName: 'Print variables'
      steps:
        - checkout: none
        - bash: |
            echo "isMain: ${{ variables.isMain }}"
            echo "isStaging: ${{ variables.isStaging }}"
            echo "isDevelop: ${{ variables.isDevelop }}"
            echo "shouldPublish: ${{ variables.shouldPublish }}"
            echo "Tag: ${{ variables.tag }}"
          displayName: 'Print variables using template syntax'
        - bash: |
            echo "isMain: $(isMain)"
            echo "isStaging: $(isStaging)"
            echo "isDevelop: $(isDevelop)"
            echo "shouldPublish: $(shouldPublish)"
            echo "Tag: $(tag)" # available at runtime
          displayName: 'Print variables using macro syntax'

Running the pipeline from the staging branch:

Please note that variable Build.SourceBranchName is available at compile time so it can be used in template expressions ${{ ... }} while Build.BuildNumber is available at runtime.
See column "Available in templates?" in Build variables.
EDIT 1
You can remove variables isMain, isStaging and isDevelop in case these are not used elsewhere:
variables:
  - name: shouldPublish
    value: ${{ in(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], parameters.releaseBranchName, parameters.stagingBranchName, parameters.buildBranchName) }}
    readonly: true

  - name: tag
    # variables have always string values
    # Use $(Build.BuildId) as an alternative to $(Build.BuildNumber) 
    ${{ if contains(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], parameters.releaseBranchName) }}:
      value: 'release.$(Build.BuildNumber)' 
    ${{ if contains(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], parameters.stagingBranchName) }}:
      value: 'staging.$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    ${{ if contains(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], parameters.buildBranchName) }}:
      value: 'build.$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    readonly: true

Further reading:

Understand variable syntax
Configure run or build numbers


@ArnaudF. added more details.
